# python opencv people detection

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to build a people detection function using opencv and python, but I need some help understanding a few things.
Images come from a mobile phone taped to a window.
Here's the code:

```
# USAGE
# python detect.py --images images

from __future__ import print_function
from glob import glob
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# parse arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# strip last / if present
arg_images = args["images"].rstrip("/")

# check folder exists
if not os.path.isdir(arg_images):
    print(arg_images + " is not a folder, terminate")
    quit()

# load images names
imagePaths = sorted(glob(arg_images + "/*.jpg"))
# check folder is not empty
if len(imagePaths) == 0:
    print(arg_images + " is empty, terminate")
    quit()

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # INTER_NEAREST - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
    # INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
    # INTER_AREA - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.
    # INTER_CUBIC - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
    # INTER_LANCZOS4 - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (min(800, image.shape[1]), min(600, image.shape[0])), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    #image = cv2.resize(image, (min(1200, image.shape[1]), min(900, image.shape[0])), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image, winStride=(4, 4), padding=(0, 0), scale=1.01)

    foldername = imagePath[0:imagePath.rfind("/")]
    filename = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]

    if len(rects) == 0:
        print("- " + filename)
    else:
        rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
        pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)

        for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        print("+ " + filename)
        cv2.imwrite(foldername + "/detected/" + filename, image)
```

When I run this function on these images ([test.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8bqrsjhpx18uxu/test.zip?dl=0)) I get very different results depending on the image size:

- 800x600: it has the least amount of false positive, roughly 40% at night and 10% during the day
- 1200x900: a lot more false positive
- original size: looks more like a random guess than a detection

Can I assume it's because detectMultiScale works with a small detection window and I can change the stride, but not the size?

Also, if you look at IMG_20180329_061603.jpg it's a false positive always detected, but I can't understand why. Night pictures looks all the same (to me), but there's too many that get a green box..

Any help with this is welcome. If you need clarifications please ask..
Thanks

Comment: "Images come from a mobile phone taped to a window" sounds somehwat sketchy to me. Are you sure this is legal in your country?

Comment: Everyone has security cameras pointed outside their door here, so I guess it's legal.
I'm trying to keep an eye on the motorbike under the cover, but I can't use motion detection because it would get triggered for every car, cat and pigeon flying by.
So I decided to get pictures at regular intervals, but now I have thousands of pictures and I'm trying to sort them and keep only those with people that I might have to notify to the police (if the worst happens).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for what you see is that the HOG descriptor used for people detection has a 64x128 window. So you want to optimize the `scale` parameter and the image sizes to get mostly true positives. You probably mostly care about a person getting near the bike, so the ones who far (and are small) are not that important. I would collect a set of "training" images to find the optimal param values. Also you're ignoring the weights returned by `detectMultiScale()`, again you can visualize those values for your true positives and false positives and find the optimal threshold.